# What are the best apps for rescuing deleted data on flash drives?

Tags: software-recommendation, damage, flash-memory

I'm searching for an app to rescue my deleted data on my flash memory. They happily deleted with a Windows virus. What's your recommendation for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [ProSoft's Data Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php) which can recover a very wide variety of [file types](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue_file_types.php). Even if you don't see the file type listed, ProSoft maybe able to help you recover the data. I once had a client delete a their QuickBook's for Mac data file. It was a new version of QuickBooks with a radically different file format from prior versions. The current Data Rescue didn't recover the data; however, ProSoft was able to provide a new file definition and all of the data was recovered.

There are separate Mac and PC versions of Data Rescue. I have used both with good results, but I have far more experience with the Mac version.

I find $99 for Data Rescue to be a very fair price, however, if you are only needing to recover image files from digital cameras, checkout ProSoft's [Image Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/picture-rescue-2.php) for $20. I believe Image Rescue comes with both Mac and PC licenses.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/features). I've also used [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover data from a corrupt flash drive.